# How do I convert wma files to ogg?

Tags: sound, repository, convert, wma

I have installed "Sound Converter" but I keep getting an error when I try to use it.  It first tells me that I need a plugin that is not installed (so I have it search) then it reports "Failed to download repository information".  I am able to install other software in the software center so what is wrong?

Comment: Do not ever transcode you sinner! You can convert from a lossless source, but don't you ever transcode from a lossy source!

Comment: Would be nice to know if you are able to play these wma files

Answer (score 3):

**Converting WMA to OGG in VLC**

- Open VLC Media Player; if you do not have VLC on your computer already, you can install it by opening a terminal window and typing "sudo apt-get install vlc."
- Go to "Media" and "Convert/Save." You can also access the window by pressing "Ctrl" and "R" on your computer.
- Click "Add" from under "File Selection" and select the WMA file that you want to convert.
- Click the "Convert/Save" button.
- Type the file name for the new OGG file in the "Destination File:" box, including the extension; for instance, "my_wma_filename.ogg."
- Select the profile "Audio - Vorbis (OGG)" from under Settings.
- Click "Start." Do not close VLC until the conversion is complete. It should be saved in your /home/username directory.

**Converting WMA to OGG Using Dir2OGG**

- Install dir2ogg by typing "sudo apt-get install dir2ogg" in a new terminal window.
- Type "dir2ogg my_wma_filename.wma" in the terminal window once installation is completed. Make sure that your WMA file is in the /home/username directory, and remove any spaces from the file name.
- If converting a directory, use dir2ogg -a /path/to/dir
- Close the terminal window once the conversion is complete. The display will read "Done encoding file "/home/username/my_wma_filename.ogg" along with the file length, elapsed time, rate and average bit rate. The "my_wma_filename.ogg" file will in the same folder as the original WMA file.

Comment: Note that dir2ogg needs the mplayer package to be installed to convert WMA files.

Answer (score 2):

Install the restricted codecs support packages and try again, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or in a terminal run this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

or look for these packages in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in a terminal to install Sound Converter:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

Sound Converter is easy and simple to use. Not to mention really quick too.

Comment: The person who posted the question said this was what they tried and it didn't work for them because of a "missing plugin". Can you please reread the question and edit your answer with advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Convert Audio, Video, Image And Document Files With FF Multi Converter

FF Multi Converter supports the following formats:

**audio/video:** aac, ac3, afc, aiff, amr, asf, au, avi, dvd, flac, flv, mka, mkv, mmf, mov, mp3, mp4, mpg, ogg, ogv, psp, rm, spx, vob, wav, webm, wma, wmv;

[image]

> Install FF Multi Converter in Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmulticonverter
```

[Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/convert-audio-video-image-and-document.html)

Comment: I found FF Multi converter very buggy on my machine and I would avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it with

**Transmageddon**

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo apt-get install transmageddon
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed:

`ubuntu-restricted-extras`
`gstreamer-ffmpeg`

If you have, then your wma files are likely encrypted, which means you would have to burn them to a CD on Windows, and then rip them to Ubuntu again.